# PHP Geo Redirect - Allow Access to Primary URL After Initial Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, cookies, geoip

Everyone!

I have inherited / set up a plugin on a WP install that redirects visitors to the correct homepage for their first visit, based on their country-of-origin.

The redirect has been built to set a `location` cookie in order to define which country the visitor is in and a `dontLoop` cookie to ignore the redirection on subsequent visits. How it should work is if the visitor is a first-time visitor, they will be redirected to the correct subdomain; if the visitor is visiting within the lifespan of the `dontLoop` cookie, they are **NOT** redirected and should have access to the entire site and its subdomains.

The issue that has come up is that it only redirects if they are trying to visit a page located within the primary URL; if they are visiting one of the subdomain directories, the redirect does not occur, regardless of whether this is their first visit or not.

So, if the visitor is from Canada and is trying to visit `https://example.com`, they **are** automatically redirected to `https://example.com/ca/`.

Similarly, if they try to visit a page on the primary domain, such as `https://example.com/item/page/`, they **are** automatically redirected to their country's correct homepage, `https://example.com/ca/`.

**HOWEVER**, if the same visitor attempts to visit one of the other subdomains, such as `https://example.com/nz/` or `https://example.com/nz/item/page/`, the visitor will **NOT** be redirected to their country's homepage.

I'm trying to allow visitors within countries outside of the US to have the following experience:

1. On first visit, redirected to their country's homepage (if visiting a page outside of their country's subdomain).
2. After the first visit, visitor can then navigate to other country subdomains (no limit, either via link or by direct URL entry).
3. After the first visit, visitor can also access the pages in the primary domain (no limit, either via link or by direct URL entry).
4. Once the 24-hour lifespan of the `dontLoop` cookie has expired, the visitor will return to bullet 1.

We think we're close — we've successfully fixed the redirection loops we were dealing with initially. We're just not sure why the visitor can navigate freely throughout the other subdomains but is not able to navigate through the primary.

Here is the plugin (I cut out the rest of the counties to save space). One item up front: we're working with WP Engine, so the `WPEngine\GeoIp` stuff at the beginning is what allows the plugin to speak with the GeoIP information collected by the host. Since the initial redirect DOES work, we know that it is successfully getting the country and firing the redirect.

```
function country_geo_redirect() {
    if ( !current_user_can('administrator') ) {
    $geo = WPEngine\GeoIp::instance();
    if(array_key_exists('override', $_COOKIE))  {
        // Do Nothing
    } else {
        $country = getenv('HTTP_GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE');
        $country = strtolower($country);
        $dontLoop = 0;
        setcookie('location',$country,time() + 24 * 3600); // 24 hours
        if($country == 'ca') {
            if(array_key_exists('dontLoop', $_COOKIE)){
                //prevent redirect
            } else {
                setcookie('dontLoop','stop',time() + 24 * 3600, '/'); // 24 hours?>
                <script language="javascript">
                    window.location.href = "https://example.com/ca"
                </script>
            <?php } 
        } else {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any references are appreciated. If there are other posts / questions that solve this, please don't hesitate to direct me to them. It's been a very long, difficult battle with the GeoIP redirections. I'm not sure if this will be a successful approach or if it needs to be handled a bit differently / tweaked.

Comment: the page will be automatically redirected to home, if we hit any subpage without that country code in url, this is the default functionality of the geo redirect js

Comment: This looks like a job for session variables as opposed to cookies. Cookies are read on the next page load and usually cannot be read immediately after they are set.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @charankumar — that makes complete sense now that I'm reading it. Are we going to be able to override that by altering the setup we have, or will we need to scrap this starting point altogether?

Comment: Thanks, @Jamie_D. I haven't worked with session variables before, so I'm going to ask a stupid question — are the variables being set by the visitor when they come to the site, or do they get set by the plugin activating? Or would they be set some other way? Again, apologies for this.

Comment: @Phil - From the code sample you provided, it looks like the only variable set by the plugin is the HTTP_GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE environment variable. As for your question "are the variables being set by the visitor when they come to the site?" , to which variables are you referring?